# Prove or disprove $f^{-1}(A - B) = f^{-1}(A)-f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, inverse-function

I'm getting that we can neither prove nor disprove it, but it seems there's a definitive answer for this. How to prove or disprove this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What are $A$ and $B$, and what kind of function is $f$? And does the minus sign mean subtraction (like in a vector space), or is it set difference?

Answer (score 1):

This is true since preimage commutes with set difference.

Theorem: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and consider a function $f: A \rightarrow B .$ Let $B_{1} \subseteq B$ and $B_{2} \subseteq B$ be any subsets. Then we have
$$
f^{-1}\left(B_{1} \backslash B_{2}\right)=f^{-1}\left(B_{1}\right) \backslash f^{-1}\left(B_{2}\right)
$$
Proof: For any given $x \in A$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
x \in f^{-1}\left(B_{1} \backslash B_{2}\right) & \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in B_{1} \backslash B_{2} \\
& \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in B_{1} \wedge f(x) \notin B_{2} \\
& \Longleftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}\left(B_{1}\right) \wedge x \notin f^{-1}\left(B_{2}\right) \\
& \Longleftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}\left(B_{1}\right) \backslash f^{-1}\left(B_{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
and therefore, since they comprise the same elements of $A$,
$$
f^{-1}\left(B_{1} \backslash B_{2}\right)=f^{-1}\left(B_{1}\right) \backslash f^{-1}\left(B_{2}\right)
$$